# Flexbox alignment to end of div

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I use flexbox to align `.right` to the very end of `div`?

My CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.right {

}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrRwxJ)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Use `justify-content: space-between` on the container.

   ```
   div {
       display: flex;
       border: 1px dotted black;
       justify-content: space-between; /* new */
   }
   ```

   [Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GorZZm)

---

2. Use `auto` margins on the first flex item.

   ```
   div > span:first-child { margin-right: auto; }
   ```

   [Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxjeeb)

---

3. Use `auto` margins on the second flex item.

   ```
   .right { margin-left: auto; }
   ```

   [Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPZKKq)

---

For an explanation of ***`justify-content`*** and ***`auto margins`***, along with examples and illustrations, see this post: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

As per [section 8.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) in the [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1), you can use `auto` margins in order to position the element.

In this case, you could add `margin-left: auto` in order to position the element to the right. In doing so, any positive free space is distributed to that side of the element which effectively positions it to the very right like in the example below.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0;` so that the element is pushed to the right! Also you have a typo here:

```
<span class="righ">Right</span>
<!---------------^ t missing.
```

See the working snippet:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</div>
```